# how to put a control vertically in center in stack panel?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

How can I put a control vertically in the center in a stackpanel?
I am doing as below:

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" Height="100" Width="200"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button Content="Hello" Height="25" Width="100"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The UI is rendering as below image. I want the button control to be placed in between of the stackpanel vertically. How can I achieve this without using Margin.

[image]

Comment: `StackPanel` is for stacking elements, not centering. You need to use another panel like a `Grid` or a `Border` to center the `Button`.

Comment: Thats true that stackpanel is for stacking the elements but if I want that the stack should be in centre then how can I do that ?

Comment: You can't do it. You position the stackpanel within a grid if you want control of the stackpanel position (and it's children)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand what you want to achieve but you can center the `StackPanel` inside a `Grid`. Whatever you put inside the `StackPanel` will be stacked as expected.

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="200">
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="Hello" Height="25" Width="100"/>
    <Button Content="Hello" Height="25" Width="100"/>
 </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is what it looks like in the XAML designer. The blue outline is the `StackPanel` and the gray outline is the `Grid`.

[image: StackPanel inside Grid]

Comment: I have also given this a try but this is not serving my purpose in the specific scenario. I just want to know that is there any way to achieve this by just setting the properties and not using any other control. Anyways thanks. :)

Comment: No, there isn't. A stackpanel doesn't position its content controls. You position the stackpanel within another layout control, such as a grid, to achieve what you want.